# How to get an SVG NOT to fill the available space?

Tags: svg, flexbox

Say I have a row of 3 icons, each 20px x 20px, then some links (however wide the link text is) then another couple of links. I'm using flexbox to space the elements and what I would like to happen is that the space between is evenly distributed between the elements. What actually happens is that the svg will increase its size to take up the entirity of the free space.

I have tried taking out the height and width attributes from the svg but the image disappears altogether. I haver also tried a wrapper div but the svg forces it to take up the remainder of the space.

Comment: if your flexbox is in *row direction* try `min-width: 0` on each of the flex children?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this post, svg does not have any intrinsic width or height so by removing the width and height attribute from the svg something higher up in the chain needs to have an explicit width or height, then the svg will fill that space.